# Show external link as subsubsite in global navigation

Tags: 2010, navigation, top-link-bar, global-navigation

I'm using SharePoint 2010. I have several different site collections, but two of them have some information that concerns both collections. Until now the same information has been maintained separately on both sites, but now we want to share a subsite to avoid double work with updating etc.

The setup is this: I have a Site collection A with a Subsite A and a Subsubsite A. I also have a site collection B with a Subsite B and subsubsites B. 
In site collection B I would like to show the link to **Subsubsite A** as a drop down under Subsite B in Global Navigation, just as the "real" subsubsites for B are shown.

I also shared a couple of other subsites from A to B earlier, but here I added the whole Subsite A as a heading and then a link to a Subsubsite A under that, which then shows as a drop down. In this new case though I don't want to show any subsite from A as a heading, only the subsubsite of A under an existing subsite on B.

P.S. The top link bar is inherited from the parent site (home page). It shows all subsites (and subsubsites as drop downs).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but judging from the tags and from what you've been describing, wouldn't the solution just consist of removing the heading for subsite A and adding a link under the heading for the subsite on B?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, I can't really delete any headings because I need them all, and I have so many subsubsites under the headings that I can't have all of those as links and buttons on the top link bar, they need to be drop-downs...

For now I have just hidden the subsite link from the top link bar and created a heading with custom links from both A and B, but I wouldn't really want to use that since the text and the links won't be updated or work if anything is done to the links or names of the subsites.